# Finding duplicates in list of dates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
x = ['2018-07-22 21:59:12.211654', '2018-07-22 22:00:12.211654', 
     '2018-07-22 22:01:12.211654', '2018-07-22 22:00:12.211654', 
     '2018-07-22 22:01:12.211654']

y = [36.37, 38.19, 40.01, 2.50, 8.99]
```

and I am trying to find duplicates in list x and if there are any, then sum values with the found duplicates index in list y. Then erase. I figured out following code:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(x)):
        if y[i] == y[j]:
            try:
                x[i] += x[j]
                x[j] = None
                y[j] = None
            except:
                pass
x = [a for a in x if a != None]
y = [a for a in y if a != None]
```

the problem is with datetime values in list x, they are being deformed. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: *duplicates in list x* but then in your code `if y[i] == y[j]:`

Comment: I must be tired that I didn´t notice, now it works! thanks

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: lists like this `x = ['2018-07-22 21:59:12.211654', '2018-07-22 22:00:12.211654', '2018-07-22 22:01:12.211654']
y = [36.37, 40.69, 49.0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine both lists into a list of tuples with `zip`, sort the list and group it by the first element (time), and apply the `sum` to the second elements:

```
from itertools import groupby
grouped_list = groupby(sorted(zip(x,y)), key=lambda x:x[0])
new_list = [(date, sum(val for _,val in vals)) 
            for date,vals in grouped_list]
```

The result is a summed list of tuples:

```
#[('2018-07-22 21:59:12.211654', 36.37), 
# ('2018-07-22 22:00:12.211654', 40.69), 
# ('2018-07-22 22:01:12.211654', 49.0)]
```

You can split this new list into x and y again:

```
x_new, y_new = zip(*new_list)
```

Comment: seems pretty elegant to me, but the if statement is missing here

Comment: There is no missing `if` statement. What do you mean?

Comment: So how do the values `sum(x for _,x in v)` know when to sum? Because they dont when I try.

Comment: I forgot to sort the list before grouping. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a dict.

Input:

```
x = ['2018-07-22 21:59:12.211654', '2018-07-22 22:00:12.211654', 
 '2018-07-22 22:01:12.211654', '2018-07-22 22:00:12.211654', 
 '2018-07-22 22:01:12.211654']
y = [36.37, 38.19, 40.01, 2.50, 8.99]

D = {}
for index,date in enumerate(x):
    if date in D.keys():
        D[date] += y[index]
    else:
        D[date] = y[index]
```

Result:

```
>>> list(D.items())
[('2018-07-22 21:59:12.211654', 36.37), 
('2018-07-22 22:00:12.211654', 40.69), ('2018-07-22 22:01:12.211654', 49.0)]
>>> x_new,y_new = zip(*list(D.items()))
>>> x_new
('2018-07-22 21:59:12.211654', '2018-07-22 22:00:12.211654', '2018-07-22 22:01:12.211654')
>>> y_new
(36.37, 40.69, 49.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for an O(n) solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(float)

for date, num in zip(x, y):
    d[date] += num
```

Result:

```
print(d)

defaultdict(float,
            {'2018-07-22 21:59:12.211654': 36.37,
             '2018-07-22 22:00:12.211654': 40.69,
             '2018-07-22 22:01:12.211654': 49.0})
```

If you require lists, you can use `zip` with unpacking (omit `map(list, ...)` if tuples are sufficient):

```
dates, values = map(list, zip(*d.items()))

print(dates, values, sep='\n')

['2018-07-22 21:59:12.211654', '2018-07-22 22:00:12.211654', '2018-07-22 22:01:12.211654']
[36.37, 40.69, 49.0]
```